# Refreshing a Django view function/sending in new parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have my default views function returning a loop of objects and status of each object in a nice little grid on my Django site.  I was hoping to add some buttons that lets the user filter down to see a smaller group of this data.  My idea was basically three radio buttons, one for the default to see everything, and the other two would refresh the loop in this div to just show the smaller group of data.

My understanding is that when this button is clicked I would have to call the views function again and pass it this additional parameter which will refresh the data presented on my site or is that not correct?  What would be the best way to do this?

```
The default view function on the home page:

def index(request):

    #Here is a bunch of code to get the status of different campuses and send it to the template via the return line below
    
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'campuses': sorted_sites, 'cc_campuses': cc_sorted_sites, 'update': update})
```

```
And here is how I display it:

            {% for campus, status in campuses %}

            <a class= "campusbutton"><div class= "item" id="{{ status }}" > {{ campus }}</div></a>
            {% endfor %}
```

What would be the best way to allow the user from the front end to click a button and call that function in views again but with new parameters so the data that shows in the template loop is customized?

Comment: If you don't require to query new data you can just change the DOM on user interaction to display the data desired using javascript. If you require a new view call you would have to make it async using Ajax for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like [this](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/).

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="refresh"> Refresh data </button>

$( "#refresh" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( ".item" ).load(location.href + " .item>*");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I reference my index function inside the views page and let the function know which of the three buttons I selected though?

Comment: The `button` on the page has its `ID` which is included in the function. If you click on it, the element of class `item` will be reloaded. You may notice that it is about the current location and `class`.